# How to fix "Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to run: `php artisan migrate`

Also to connect to MySQL using Xampp on Windows.

I Got this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access
denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'homestead' (SQL: select *
from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and
table_name = migrations)

  at
C:\Users\harsh\Laravel1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user
''@'localhost' to database 'homestead'")
      C:\Users\harsh\Laravel1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  2  
PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead",
"homestead", "", [])
      C:\Users\harsh\Laravel1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

**.env file:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=homestead 
DB_USERNAME=homestead 
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Set your database user name inside your `.env` file. and run `php artisan cache:clear` from console inside your project root.

Comment: What's in your `config/database.php` and `.env` file? (don't forget to remove passwords!)

Comment: @Jerodev I removed passwords, and made an edit with other details of .env, still doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN I've added .env connection details, still doesn't fix things, please see what's wrong.

Comment: Did you actually create a database and user named `homestead`?

Comment: Do you really use homestead? If so, did you remove the password? The default password is `secret`.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time, issue was solved, please see the answer below. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open the *`.env`* file and edit it. Just set up correct DB credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Yout Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

The *`DB_USERNAME`* should be set to *`root`* if you do not have a default **username** in the installation of MySQL in **xampp**.

If no password is set on the database, clear it *`DB_PASSWORD`*, **empty space must also be removed**(In the past I've also faceout this problem, window consider blank space as a password)

After completion of *`.env`* edit please enter this command in your terminal for clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Hey, that helped, but now it says "Illuminate\Database\QueryException: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))" Please tell a fix for that as well.

Comment: @indiadevelops Edit your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file and inside the boot() method set a default string length: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}`

Comment: Now it says "Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `email` varchar(191) not null, `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(191) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')"

Comment: @indiadevelops You need to delete (if you have) `users table` and `password_resets` table from the database also **delete users** and **password_resets** entries from `migrations` table.

Comment: why it req root, describe the required previl would be better

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users using MAMP, if the accepted answer was not enough to solve this issue, like me, add `socket` to the `.env` file.

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
//or
UNIX_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

The variable should match with the setting on `config > database.php`. Look for `connections > mysql > unix_socket`

Answer (score 1):

Hi go to xampp phpmyadmin create a database for exemple stack and change your .env to this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=stack
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=
```

by default phpmyadmin username is root and without password
save and try `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Thanks for your time, issue was solved, please see the accepted answer and comment discussion on it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=your database name 
DB_USERNAME= your localhost-database username (i.e `root`)
DB_PASSWORD= your localhost-database password (i.e `root`)
```

then you run below command

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, issue was solved, please see the accepted answer and comment discussion on it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, go to your *`.env`* file, change the name of the database.
Go to your phpmyadmin, create a new database with the new name in your *`.env`* file.

Then run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same error until I changed the `DB_PORT` and set the value from MAMP

Comment: Changed the DB PORT to what? Set what value from MAMP? Please be more descriptive in your answers in the future, answers that offer value to readers.

Answer (score 0):

ensure your .env file is correct

Go to *mysql/data/database_name /tablename.ibd* file and delete it manually. after this try your command php artisan migrate

for windows e.g
**C:\xampp\mysql\data\vogDB\tablename.ibd** <======

1. `php artisan config:cache`
2. `php artisan migrate`
3. `php artisan serve`

Comment: Why would he need to do this low-level steps when he can simply delete the database using a software like phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: this solution should be your last resort if phpMyAdmin doesn't work due to cache or administartive issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your terminal: To start XMAPP use

```html
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Console output should be

```html
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.4.8-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP: Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

When you get the error

```html
error: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 264: kill: No such process**
```

try this again in your terminal:

```html
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Then open datatbase after migrating the file.

Answer (score -1):

```
you fix file .env Pay attention to the password section 'password'
 +need to have '
 
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
 DB_PORT=3306 
 DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
 DB_USERNAME=           // Yout Database Username
 DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer by removing the `enter code here` lines?

Comment: Please share more details - to me, this looks like the answer already given two years ago

Answer (score -1):

I'm using MacOS and MAMP

I tried the above mentioned suggestions but I couldn't solve it.

What solved it for me was **switching from PHP 7.x to 8.0.x in MAMP**.