# running "php artisan migrate" but it's throwing error (Laravel,OpenServer )

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run **php artisan migrate** but it's throwing error ( framework - Laravel, server - OpenServer )

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel_blog and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

[image]

MySQL driver information in .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: What OS are you using? This is telling you that you don't have a (my)SQL driver installed in PHP

Comment: Windows (10)   - OS

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this. Are you added credentials properly ? please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124262/how-to-fix-illuminate-database-queryexception-sqlstatehy000-1044-access-de also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php.ini configuration file simply uncomment (remove semicolon) the extension:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

And restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from the other answer, if you uncommented

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

and it still doesn't work, uncomment the following also:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

this is required if you use sqlite as your database instead of mysql

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Amri! Although I appreciate you contributing an answer to this question it was clear in the question that they were trying to connect to a MySQL database. Please in future only add an answer if it is relevant to the question. I hope you have a great experience and thank you for helping our fellow developers!